# Can a faulty GU10 bulb trip RCD?

Tags: led

Recently during a rain shower one of the RCD's tripped which I isolated to the outside lights.  Soon after it again tripped one night.  On both occasions the RCD does not stay tripped so I have not been able to isolate further other than knowing which MCB it relates to.   It hasn't happened again for a few days.  I discovered that one of the up-lighters had a faulty GU10 LED bulb and another had no bulb even though the screw in top is meant to be waterproof.  It was like this for at least 2 years.  However could a faulty bulb be suddenly causing the RCD to trip?  The only other lights on this circuit are 2 PIR floodlights which are less than 2 years old.

Comment: Age doesn't really matter. If the waterproofing on the lights *or their connections* isn't done well, the box could easily be full of water.

Answer (score 3):

It takes a lot to trip an RCD.

A GU10 socket does not deliver earth to the bulb, so I don't see what possible manipulation a bulb could do to trip an RCD *even if it was purpose-designed to do that*.

So I consider that "highly improbable".

Especially since the RCD trip is intermittent, and that is not how a faulty bulb would trip (even if it had access to earth).